# Powershell - Return node at index regardless of type

Tags: xml, powershell

Say I have this xml:

```
  $xml = [xml]@'
    <messages>
      <message name="Advertisement" msgtype="7" msgcat="app">
        <field name="AdvId" required="Y" />
        <field name="AdvTransType" required="Y" />
        <field name="AdvRefID" required="N" />
        <component name="Instrument" required="Y" />
        <component name="Balls" required="Y" />
        <field name="AdvSide" required="Y" />
        <field name="Quantity" required="Y" />
      </message>
    </messages>
'@
```

I expect the results below, but nothing is returned:

```
$xml.messages.message[1] # should return <field name="AdvTransType" required="Y" />
$xml.messages.message[3] # should return <component name="Instrument" required="Y" />
```

Is there a function I'm missing? I want to access nodes via index...

powershell version: `6.0.0 alpha`

Comment: Derp. Thank you @wOxxOm!!. Should just start pinging you directly for my questions :). If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML tree named node notation returns an array of the specified nodes so `message[1]` means 2nd `message` but you have only one `message`.

To access the sub-nodes by index regardless of type use a special property `ChildNodes`:

```
$xml.messages.message.ChildNodes[1]
```

> ```
> name         required
> ----         --------
> AdvTransType Y
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
 $xml.messages.message.field[1]
 $xml.messages.message.field[2]
```

Comment: The question title says `regardless of type`.